# Change rows button image source on click?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, sections

I am trying to implement code for changing a row's button image source on click of the row. This is for a checklist table view.The table view is split into sections. Not sure what I'm doing wrong:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    //change tickBtn's image src to tick.png
    print("in didselect")
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? CheckListCell {
        let tickedImg = UIImage(named: "tick.png")
        cell.tickBtn.setImage(tickedImg, forState: UIControlState.Selected)
        //cell.tickBtn.alpha = 0

    }
    else{
        print("in the else of didSelect")
    }

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    //change tickBtn's image src to unTicked.png
    print("in didDeselect")
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? CheckListCell{
        let tickedImg = UIImage(named: "unTicked.png")
        cell.tickBtn.setImage(tickedImg, forState: UIControlState.Selected)
        //cell.tickBtn.alpha = 1
    }
    else{
        print("in the else of didDeSelect")
    }

}
```

I'm getting the logs for didSelect and didDeSelect but the image source is not changing. Must be something to do with how i'm accessing the cell and I need to take into account the section?

**UPDATE:**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    //change tickBtn's image src to tick.png
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? CheckListCell
    cell!.cellTickedImage = UIImage(named: "tick.png")
    self.checkListTableView.beginUpdates()
    self.checkListTableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    self.checkListTableView.endUpdates()

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? CheckListCell
    cell!.cellTickedImage = UIImage(named: "unTicked.png")
    self.checkListTableView.beginUpdates()
    self.checkListTableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    self.checkListTableView.endUpdates()
}

class CheckListCell : UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var tickBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var taskLbl: UILabel!
    var cellTickedImage : UIImage?

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = checkListTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CheckListCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CheckListCell

        cell.taskLbl?.text = checkListData[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        cell.tickBtn.setImage(cell.cellTickedImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        cell.tickBtn.setImage(cell.cellTickedImage, forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)

        //cell.tickBtn.titleLabel!.text = ""

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: @DharmeshKheni Yes, just in the view controller with all the tableview methods

Comment: Without alpha value, is your didselect working fine?

Comment: @Vijay Ok, so whats happening is when I tap on a row, I am getting the log for didDeSelect and didSelect, in that order. Then if I tap on the row a second, third, fourth x times after, I am just getting the didSelect

Comment: So I feel you can't achieve what you want with this approach. You need to reload the specific row to toggle the tick image

Comment: Can you show your cell for row at indexpath?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this out:

**Step 1 :** In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` update the model that drives cell image:

```
self.cellTickedImage = UIImage(named: "tick.png”)
```

**Step 2 :** In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` reload the cell to see the change:

```
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

**Step 3 :** In `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` update the model that drives cell image:

```
self.cellTickedImage = UIImage(named: "unTicked.png”)
```

**Step 4 :** In `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` reload the cell to see the change:

```
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

**Step 5 :** In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` set the cell image correctly:

```
cell.tickBtn.setImage(self.cellTickedImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
cell.tickBtn.setImage(self.cellTickedImage, forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)
```

**EDIT:** Post discussion with OP on chat - Few assumptions from discussion

1. No two cells shall have same text on it.
2. On one tap show one image and on second tap show second image.

Considering this, here is the high level algorithm for the fix:

1. Create a global dictionary `checkListDict` with key as cell text and value as image status flag. Initially set value is 0 for all cell text. Considering 1 as `tick.png` and 0 as `unTicked.png`.
2. In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` update the flag like this:

->

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) { 
   //change tickBtn's image src to tick.png 
   let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? CheckListCell 
   let selectedCellText = (cell!.taskLbl?.text)!

   if checkListDict[selectedCellText] == 0 { 
      checkListDict[selectedCellText] = 1 
   } 
   else{ 
      checkListDict[selectedCellText] = 0 
   } 

   self.checkListTableView.beginUpdates() 
   self.checkListTableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic) 
   self.checkListTableView.endUpdates()
}
```

3. Finally, use the updated model in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` like this:

->

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = checkListTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CheckListCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CheckListCell

    let selectedCellText = checkListData[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

    cell.taskLbl?.text = selectedCellText
    let cellImage = checkListDict[selectedCellText] == 0 ? UIImage(named: "unTicked.png")  : UIImage(named:"tick.png") 


    cell.tickBtn.setImage(cellImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    cell.tickBtn.setImage(cellImage, forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)

    return cell
}
```

Comment: I just got it working with the method in my update, is there any advantage of implemeting it your way as opposed to mine?

Comment: I think you are doing it the right way! Good to know it sorted out!

Comment: my method did not work at all, as i scroll up and down, different rows were randomly changing img src. I'm trying your method now..Only question is where how do I define cellTickedImage?

Comment: Define `cellTickedImage ` at class level. It should be a global property to be accessible from all class functions.

Comment: the class is class currently as follows, so how would cellTickedImage be defined in there? There is no outlet? CheckListCell : UITableViewCell {
    
    IBOutlet weak var tickBtn: UIButton!
    IBOutlet weak var taskLbl: UILabel!
    
}

Comment: Just put `var cellTickedImage : UIImage` after your `class` definition. Like `class MyViewController: UIViewController {  var cellTickedImage : UIImage`

Comment: Okay I'll update the q. Basically I'm getting the same behaviour as before with my previous method, scrolling up and down is changing random rows. But noww, even when I press a second time, I am getting no change in image src :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93669/discussion-between-abhinav-and-user2363025).

Comment: @user2363025 Since this worked for you, for the benefit of others, please accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

did you try setting the image for normal state also?

Cause what i can infer from your given code, is that you are only setting the selected state image. 
And button is always in normal state.
So try setting the image for normal state also.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

Step 1: make array have same element with your number of row. And in viewDidload set:

```
for (i = 0; i < NumberElement; i++) {
    [self.listState addObject:@"0"];
}
```

Step 2: At cellForRowAtIndexPath check it:

```
let tickedImg = UIImage(named: "unTicked.png")
    cell.tickBtn.setImage(tickedImg, forState: UIControlState.Selected
let untickedImg = UIImage(named: "ticked.png")
cell.tickBtn.setImage(untickedImg, forState: UIControlstate.Normal)
if self.listState[indexPath.row) == 0  {
   cell.tickBtn.selected = false
} else {
   cell.tickBtn.selected = true
}
```

Step 3: In didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
if self.listState[indexPath.row] == "0" {
  self.listState[indexPath.row] = "1"
} else {
  self.listState[indexPath.row] = "0"
}
//Start reload cell 
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

Hope this help. 
P/s: you can make some nicer approach.